# as.Date.numeric : 'origin' must by supplied

Tags: r, ggplot2, numeric, as.date

I am trying to get this ggplot to load and when ever I do it gives me this error:

```
Error in as.Date.numeric(value) : 'origin' must be supplied
```

This is the only related code that has to due with the as.Date function:

```
boxdates<-as.numeric(as.Date(c('1990-01-05','1992-01-05','1994-01-05','1996-01-05','1998-01-05',
                           '2000-01-05','2002-01-05','2004-01-05','2006-01-05','2008-01-05',
                           '2010-01-05','2012-01-05','2014-01-05','2016-01-05','2018-01-05')))

boxlegend<-format(as.Date(boxdates),'%Y')
```

And here is how those variables are used in ggplot:

```
scale_fill_gradientn(colors=c("#66355A", "#9E0808", "#C45608", "#C4933D", "#3A8026", "#716FB3"),
                   breaks=boxdates, labels=boxlegend)+
scale_color_gradientn(colors=c("#66355A", "#9E0808", "#C45608", "#C4933D", "#3A8026", "#716FB3"),
                    breaks=boxdates, labels=boxlegend)
```

Any idea what is wrong with these?

I have tried removing boxdates and boxlegend from the scale_fill_gradients and it still gives the same error,  I have also played around with the variables, nothing changes.  And boxdates and boxlegends run fine and give exactly what they are supposed to give, it's just when they are put in ggplot.

Here is the whole code for anyone curious:

```
# Return Box Plots #######

# Calculate n-day rolling returns (discrete or continuous)
daily.ret <- ROC(Adj.Close, n=1, type='discrete')
three.ret <- ROC(Adj.Close, n=3, type='discrete')
five.ret <- ROC(Adj.Close, n=5, type='discrete')
ten.ret <- ROC(Adj.Close, n=10, type='discrete')
monthly.ret <- ROC(Adj.Close, n=21, type='discrete')
quarterly.ret <- ROC(Adj.Close, n=63, type='discrete')
semiannual.ret <- ROC(Adj.Close, n=126, type='discrete')
annual.ret <- ROC(Adj.Close, n=252, type='discrete')

# Merge short-term and longer-term returns xts objects and rename columns
# name the columns
short.rets <- merge(daily.ret,three.ret,five.ret,ten.ret)
names(short.rets) <- c('One','Three','Five','Ten')

long.rets <- merge(monthly.ret,quarterly.ret,semiannual.ret,annual.ret)
names(long.rets) <- c('Monthly','Quarterly','SixMonth','Annual')

# Convert to df and melt
short.rets.df <- data.frame(times=time(short.rets),short.rets)
melted.short.rets <- melt(short.rets.df, id='times')

long.rets.df <- data.frame(times=time(long.rets),long.rets)
melted.long.rets <- melt(long.rets.df, id='times')


# The following lines are for the purpose of automating y-axis labels
# Step 1 - Calculate the range
shortbox.y.range <- max(melted.short.rets$value,na.rm = T)-min(melted.short.rets$value, na.rm = T)
longbox.y.range <- max(melted.long.rets$value,na.rm = T)-min(melted.long.rets$value, na.rm = T)

# Step 2 - Use the range to determine what increment to use for y-axis breaks
shortbox.y.increment <- ifelse(shortbox.y.range>4,.5,
                               ifelse(shortbox.y.range>2,.2,
                                      ifelse(shortbox.y.range>1,.1,.05)))
longbox.y.increment <- ifelse(longbox.y.range>4,.5,
                              ifelse(longbox.y.range>2,.2,
                                     ifelse(longbox.y.range>1,.1,.05)))

# Step 3- Create a vector from the min rounded down, to the max rounded up, 
# in increments of the calculated value (floor rounds down & ceiling rounds up)
shortbox.y.breaks <- seq(from=floor(min(melted.short.rets$value,na.rm = T)), 
                         to=ceiling(max(melted.short.rets$value,na.rm = T)), 
                         by=shortbox.y.increment)
longbox.y.breaks <- seq(from=floor(min(melted.long.rets$value,na.rm = T)), 
                        to=ceiling(max(melted.long.rets$value,na.rm = T)), 
                        by=longbox.y.increment)

# Step 4 - Multiply by 100 and add a '%' for labeling
shortbox.y.labels <- paste0(round(shortbox.y.breaks,2)*100,'%')
longbox.y.labels <- paste0(round(longbox.y.breaks,2)*100,'%')

# For the legend - first we have to specify breaks for the legend (boxdates), then we specify
# the labels (boxlegend), Jan 5 is used because of holidays and such

boxdates<-as.numeric(as.Date(c('1992-01-05','1994-01-05','1996-01-05','1998-01-05',
                               '2000-01-05','2002-01-05','2004-01-05','2006-01-05','2008-01-05',
                               '2010-01-05','2012-01-05','2014-01-05','2016-01-05','2018-01-05',"2019-01-05")))

boxlegend<-format(as.Date(boxdates),'%Y')

boxdates.annual<-as.numeric(as.Date(c('2004-01-05','2005-01-05','2006-01-05','2007-01-05',
                                      '2008-01-05','2009-01-05','2010-01-05','2011-01-05','2012-01-05',
                                      '2013-01-05','2014-01-05','2015-01-05','2016-01-05','2017-01-05',
                                      '2018-01-05','2019-01-05')))

boxlegend.annual<-format(as.Date(boxdates.annual),'%Y')


# Subsetting to make top 2% and bottom 2% bigger
# these subsets work with the melted data
dailysub<- subset(melted.short.rets,subset=variable=='One')
threesub<- subset(melted.short.rets,subset=variable=='Three')
fivesub<- subset(melted.short.rets,subset=variable=='Five')
tensub<- subset(melted.short.rets,subset=variable=='Ten')
monthsub<- subset(melted.long.rets,subset=variable=='Monthly')
quartersub<- subset(melted.long.rets,subset=variable=='Quarterly')
sixmonthsub<- subset(melted.long.rets,subset=variable=='SixMonth')
annualsub<- subset(melted.long.rets,subset=variable=='Annual')

#This may be used to help with automation in the future
QB <-.99
QS <- 1-QB

QB2 <- .95
QS2 <- 1-QB2

Dot <- 7
SDot <- .3

dailysub$size<- ifelse(dailysub$value >= quantile(dailysub$value, .99,na.rm = T),3,
                       ifelse(dailysub$value <= quantile(dailysub$value, .01, na.rm = T),3,
                              ifelse(dailysub$value >= quantile(dailysub$value, .95,na.rm = T),2,
                                     ifelse(dailysub$value <= quantile(dailysub$value, .05, na.rm = T),2,NA))))
threesub$size<- ifelse(threesub$value >= quantile(threesub$value, .99,na.rm = T),3,
                       ifelse(threesub$value <= quantile(threesub$value, .01, na.rm = T),3,
                              ifelse(threesub$value >= quantile(threesub$value, .95,na.rm = T),2,
                                     ifelse(threesub$value <= quantile(threesub$value, .05, na.rm = T),2,NA))))
fivesub$size<- ifelse(fivesub$value >= quantile(fivesub$value, .99,na.rm = T),3,
                      ifelse(fivesub$value <= quantile(fivesub$value, .01, na.rm = T),3,
                             ifelse(fivesub$value >= quantile(fivesub$value, .95,na.rm = T),2,
                                    ifelse(fivesub$value <= quantile(fivesub$value, .05, na.rm = T),2,NA))))
tensub$size<- ifelse(tensub$value >= quantile(tensub$value, .99,na.rm = T),3,
                     ifelse(tensub$value <= quantile(tensub$value, .01, na.rm = T),3,
                            ifelse(tensub$value >= quantile(tensub$value, .95,na.rm = T),2,
                                   ifelse(tensub$value <= quantile(tensub$value, .05, na.rm = T),2,NA))))
monthsub$size<- ifelse(monthsub$value >= quantile(monthsub$value, .99,na.rm = T),3,
                       ifelse(monthsub$value <= quantile(monthsub$value, .01, na.rm = T),3,
                              ifelse(monthsub$value >= quantile(monthsub$value, .95,na.rm = T),2,
                                     ifelse(monthsub$value <= quantile(monthsub$value, .05, na.rm = T),2,NA))))
quartersub$size<- ifelse(quartersub$value >= quantile(quartersub$value, .99,na.rm = T),3,
                         ifelse(quartersub$value <= quantile(quartersub$value, .01, na.rm = T),3,
                                ifelse(quartersub$value >= quantile(quartersub$value, .95,na.rm = T),2,
                                       ifelse(quartersub$value <= quantile(quartersub$value, .05, na.rm = T),2,NA))))
sixmonthsub$size<- ifelse(sixmonthsub$value >= quantile(sixmonthsub$value, .99,na.rm = T),3,
                          ifelse(sixmonthsub$value <= quantile(sixmonthsub$value, .01, na.rm = T),3,
                                 ifelse(sixmonthsub$value >= quantile(sixmonthsub$value, .95,na.rm = T),2,
                                        ifelse(sixmonthsub$value <= quantile(sixmonthsub$value, .05, na.rm = T),2,NA))))
annualsub$size<- ifelse(annualsub$value >= quantile(annualsub$value, .99,na.rm = T),3,
                        ifelse(annualsub$value <= quantile(annualsub$value, .01, na.rm = T),3,
                               ifelse(annualsub$value >= quantile(annualsub$value, .95,na.rm = T),2,
                                      ifelse(annualsub$value <= quantile(annualsub$value, .05, na.rm = T),2,NA))))

#we subsetted the original, and now we're putting the individual fragments back together
melted.short.rets2<-rbind(dailysub,threesub,fivesub,tensub)
melted.long.rets2<-rbind(monthsub,quartersub,sixmonthsub,annualsub)


shortbox <- ggplot(melted.short.rets2, aes(x=variable, y=value))+
  geom_jitter(aes(fill=times,color=times),width=.37,alpha=.8, size=melted.short.rets2$size, shape=21)+ 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=shortbox.y.breaks,labels=shortbox.y.labels)+
  scale_x_discrete(labels= c('1-day','3-day','5-day','10-day'))+
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors=c("#66355A", "#9E0808", "#C45608", "#C4933D", "#3A8026", "#716FB3"),
                       breaks=boxdates, labels=boxlegend)+
  scale_color_gradientn(colors=c("#66355A", "#9E0808", "#C45608", "#C4933D", "#3A8026", "#716FB3"),
                        breaks=boxdates, labels=boxlegend)+
  stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar", width=.1, size=1) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape=NA, fill='white', colour="black",size=.75)+
  labs(title=paste0(asset," Return Distributions\n"),y='Return\n',x='')+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(plot.title=element_text(hjust=.5,size=44-max(0,nchar(asset)-6),face='bold'),
        axis.text=element_text(size=22,face='bold',color='black'),
        axis.title=element_text(size=32,face='bold'),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 22, color = 'black', face='bold'),
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.y =  element_line(colour = "grey40"),
        panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_rect(color = 'black',size = 3),
        legend.key.height = unit(2.25,'cm'),
        axis.ticks = element_line(size = 1),
        axis.ticks.length = unit(2,'mm'),
        plot.margin=unit(c(1,1,1,1),"cm"))

longbox <- ggplot(melted.long.rets2, aes(x=variable, y=value))+
  geom_jitter(aes(fill=times,color=times),width=.37,alpha=.8, size=melted.long.rets2$size, shape=21)+ 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=longbox.y.breaks, labels=longbox.y.labels)+
  scale_x_discrete(labels=c('Monthly','Quarterly','Semiannual','Annual'))+
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors=c("#66355A", "#9E0808", "#C45608", "#C4933D", "#3A8026", "#716FB3"),
                       breaks=boxdates,labels=boxlegend)+
  scale_color_gradientn(colors=c("#66355A", "#9E0808", "#C45608", "#C4933D", "#3A8026", "#716FB3"),
                        breaks=boxdates,labels=boxlegend)+
  stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar", width=0.1, size=1) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.colour=NA, fill='white', colour="black",size=.75)+
  labs(title=paste0(asset," Return Distributions\n"),y='Return\n',x='')+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(plot.title=element_text(hjust=.5,size=44-max(0,nchar(asset)-6),face='bold'),
        axis.text=element_text(size=22,face='bold',color='black'),
        axis.title=element_text(size=32,face='bold'),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 22, color = 'black', face='bold'),
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.y =  element_line(colour = "grey40"),
        panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_rect(color = 'black',size = 3),
        legend.key.height = unit(2.25,'cm'),
        axis.ticks = element_line(size = 1),
        axis.ticks.length = unit(2,'mm'),
        plot.margin=unit(c(1,1,1,1),"cm"))
```

Comment: Try running the conversion: `as.Date(boxdates, origin = "1970-01-01")`

Comment: Thank you Adam!  One question, where exactly do you think I should insert this code?  I seems as though it would fit in the defining box dates part of the code, but you use the variable in it so that wouldn't work.  Could you please clarify?

Comment: Can you add complete data and plot code that you are using for `ggplot` ?

Comment: Sure but there is a lot.  I'll add it right now!

Answer (score 0):

Changing:

```
boxlegend<-format(as.Date(boxdates),'%Y')
```

to:

```
boxlegend<-format(as.Date(boxdates,  origin = "1970-01-01"),'%Y')
```

will resolve your origin error. You can also reference [origin](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lubridate/versions/1.7.4/topics/origin) from the library lubridate

For quick examples of R and Plotly plots check out [VisualisingValues](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCZqasDer-RZ8-cYGjSjBnxA/videos)

Comment: Thank you for your time, but I am still having the same problem.  I put it in and nothing changed at all and the same error pops up, any ideas?

Comment: Interesting... I wonder if there is an issue with your System local for recognising the format of the date string. You could try adding `format = "%Y-%m-%d"` as an extra argument to your as.Date() functions. So you code would look like:

`boxdates<-as.numeric(as.Date(c('1990-01-05','1992-01-05','1994-01-05','1996-01-05','1998-01-05', '2000-01-05','2002-01-05','2004-01-05','2006-01-05','2008-01-05', '2010-01-05','2012-01-05','2014-01-05','2016-01-05','2018-01-05'), format = "%Y-%m-%d"))
 
boxlegend<-format(as.Date(boxdates, origin = "1970-01-01", format = "%Y-%m-%d"),'%Y')`

Comment: Sorry it took a while to respond, but same problem.  I have tried everything and just can't find out the problem.  Thanks for your time, and if you have any more ideas that would be great, but I just don't know if there is an easy solution.